# Redirect to same controller after login

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I want to check login in every controller of my project. if there is no session data i want to redirect to login page and after login i want to come back to same controller.

Thank you.

Comment: define one common sessionchecking function in helpers or libraries, when you are loading the project autoload those helpers/libraries if session is empty  redirect to login page

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [IonAuth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) which is an authentication library for CodeIgniter. If installed, you can simply write something along the lines of:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('ion_auth');

        $identity = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        if ($this->ion_auth->login($identity, $password, true)) {
            redirect('user/dashboard');    
        }

        redirect('user/login');
    }

}
```